# How to prevent the child from affecting parent in expandablelistview android?

Tags: android, parent-child, expandablelistview, childviews

Here I have `expandablelistview` in activity and as child I have dynamic `TableView` which is added into `FrameLayout`.

When I scroll `TableView` vertically then it affect its parent `scrollview` that means whole `ExpandableListview` scrolled. Now I want that when I scroll TableView Content at that time I don't want to scroll ExpandableListView.

I have also tried `v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` and googling for that but i didn't get any solutions.

Help me guys.

Comment: Wait you have a child listview inside of another one? That is not right at all....

Comment: No. I have TableView with vertical scroll as child.

Comment: Pretty sure nesting a scrollable view inside of another breaks things. Otherwise I'm not sure, good luck

Comment: Yes I know but I have to do it any how. I will try my best... Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I mean if I may suggest something. if you MUST have a nested scrollable, why not just do it where you have dummy views in your listview and when someone wants to scroll through the child you disable the list-view, and use a transparent FrameLayout to which you add a perfect replica of the child which is now scrollable. That's how I would do it at least. It would probably be easier with a recycler View though.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what are you trying to say but my major problem is when I expand all groups in expandablelistview and scroll to the item who contain TableView then scrolling TableView content affect parent scrollview. Paricular  group that contain TableView is expanded then its working pretty fine. but when all the group expanded then its not working properly.